# HAML link_to is not clickable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, haml, link-to

I'm very new to haml, i need it to do rails project.
I don't understand why this code does not provide clickable link in the header of column.
For example:

```
  %table#movies
    %thread
       %tr
         %th <%= link_to "Name", :sort => "name" %>
         %th Year
         %th Rating
```

and so on...

All it displays is just plain text of what I wrote instead link in Name column.
This is probably extremely stupid question, but I could find solution anywhere, sorry

Or if there is a way to send :sort parameter within simple html 'a' tag, could you please tell. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to append rails output to html tag you must use another syntax (http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#inserting_ruby_)

Change

```
%th <%= link_to "Name", :sort => "name" %>
```

to

```
%th= link_to "Name", :sort => "name"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
%th=link_to "Name", "#" ,:sort => "name"
```